# Convert an existing Silverlight application to a desktop based application

Tags: silverlight, desktop-application, silverlight-oob

I have developed a business application using Silverlight, for data access I have used web service..(basicHttpBinding) (highly uses MS SQL Server - SP, Functions)

I want to convert same application to Desktop based application. 
I have tried in OOB.

1. Using ComToolkit, ADO connection (best method for my project) but data comes very very slow (1 row in 5 sec.)
2. Installed Application to client localhost. (but I don't want to go with this method. I want .exe type project..)

Now is there any good idea or suggestion? What to do in this situation?

Comment: Out of browser application or WPF isn't ok for you?

Comment: Wpf is ok for me but how to convert same application to wpf ..that i don't to change much codding.

Comment: The minimum effort for you to convert it to a desktop app is to use the out of browser application. To convert it to WPF you will need to change some code and XAML since it's not the same as Silverlight, but it will be faster then to rewrite the code to any other language.

Comment: yes the problem is changing code in wpf.. in updation of the application i have to change code in both.. that's why i want to prefer OOB. but in OOB big problem is access local database..

Answer (score 0):

Well I would go for WPF, since it is the fastest way I think.

Please read this if it helps: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/3898.aspx